# Spring Boot doesn't load application.yml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple main app:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "dreamteam.eho")
    @Import({EhoConfig.class})
    public class MainApp implements CommandLineRunner, ApplicationContextAware {
```

With config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({RootProperties.class})
public class EhoConfig {
}
```

And properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("root")
public class RootProperties {
    private String name;
```

I try to load config:

```
--spring.config.location=file:///E:/.../eho-bot/props/ --spring.profiles.active=eho
```

Path is correct. But yml isn't loaded;

application-eho.yml file:

```
logging:
  file: D:/java/projects/telegram-bots/eho.log
  level:
    dreamteam.eho: INFO
    org.springframework: DEBUG

root:
  name: EHO-BOT
```

App runs with args, but all props null. Logging properties not aplied;
sout:

```
--spring.config.location=file:///E:.../eho-bot/props/

--spring.profiles.active=eho

--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough info. For example, what does the rest of your main class look like? Have you passed its args into the SpringApplication that it runs?

Comment: `@EnableConfigurationProperties` is not required in my opinion. What exception are you getting?

Comment: args from app: ```--spring.config.location=file:///E:/Dropbox/Programming/java/telegram-bots-app/eho-bot/props/```

```--spring.profiles.active=eho```

```--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always```

Comment: That doesn't help. We need to see all of the code in `MainApp`, most importantly its `main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: -Dspring.profiles.active=test  <- I normally pass it as jvm parameter and it works

Comment: We had a similar issue and were able to resolve using this:
Added @PropertySource("file:C:/Users/apps/config/application.yml") at the class declaration level for Spring Boot's Application.java. Another thing we found out that if we changed the name of application.yml to anything else like application2.yml, it doesn't get picked up. May be you can try that. Please let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this moment you should use spring-boot.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ReTestsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(ReTestsApplication.class);
            application.setWebEnvironment(false);
            application.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
            application.run(args);
        }

        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        }
    }
```

Use webEnvironmet=false, and BannerMode=off (console application).

Docs, see 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-externalize-configuration

Comment: I have that it still doesnt load my eureka URL i set in application.yml

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way :**

> Follow application structure like **:**

```
App
└── src
|    ├── main
|         ├── java
|         │     └── <base-package>
|         │               └── Application.java (having public static void main() method)
|         │
|         ├── resources
|                ├─── application-eho.yml
|
├──── pom.xml
```

> **Application.java** content

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "application-eho");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

> **application-eho.yml** file:

```
logging:
  file: D:/java/projects/telegram-bots/eho.log
  level:
    dreamteam.eho: INFO
    org.springframework: DEBUG

root:
  name: EHO-BOT
```

Comment: This won't help. The OP is trying to use a profile-specific configuration file. Boot looks for `application-eho.properties` and `application-eho.yml` because the `eho` profile is active. Setting the name as you have would mean that it looks for `application-eho-eho.properties` and `application-eho-eho.yml`.

Comment: Did u make that "eho profile is active." ?? Simple suggesion is dont do any other configurations.. Just do as I did in Application.java class.
Its working for me .. In application like "microservices".

Comment: I have application.yml in that folder but still doesnt load eureka url

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `PropertySource` annotation then it is not possible. Be default it doesn't support yml file types. use `PropertySourceFactory` as below

```
    public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) 
      throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

Then, refer to the same in your property source annotation as follows:

```
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:foo.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
```

Source: [PropertySourceFactory](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource)

Answer (score 0):

Add the

`@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")`
in the main class

Checkout the example below:

`@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
public class TestSpringApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestSpringApplication.class, args);
    }
}`